# Pre-install device drivers

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, driver, bluetooth

I do not have a USB plug-and-play keyboard for my Raspberry Pi. I do have however a Bluetooth keyboard and a USB Bluetooth dongle. The problem is I have no way to configure my Raspberry Pi during installation.

I remember there was an option with Windows/Ubuntu where you were able to repackage the `.iso` image to add your own software/drivers to be installed during the OS installation.

What are my alternatives here?

Comment: Best way is to compile your own kernel. Its a bit tough but you get to choose exactly what you want and what you don't want. Making your Pi faster if you remove crap from the bootup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well google will provide your answer

[generate custom linux image](http://www.maketecheasier.com/6-tools-to-easily-create-your-own-custom-linux-distro/)

it is a lil about which distro you want to use.. if you can give more informations i can update my answer maybe..

furthermore.. why you do not install and configure your pi and make an image from the final state?